# MAUI MAP - How to get the address, city and country name from Location?

Tags: maui

As we can see in the google map, how we can get the name of *city, address,
road name/street name etc..* from a given latitude and longitude using
**Microsoft MAUI Map? (Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is called [reverse geocoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/device/geocoding?tabs=android#reverse-geocoding)

```
IEnumerable<Placemark> placemarks = await Geocoding.Default.GetPlacemarksAsync(latitude, longitude);

    Placemark placemark = placemarks?.FirstOrDefault();

    if (placemark != null)
    {
        return
            $"AdminArea:       {placemark.AdminArea}\n" +
            $"CountryCode:     {placemark.CountryCode}\n" +
            $"CountryName:     {placemark.CountryName}\n" +
            $"FeatureName:     {placemark.FeatureName}\n" +
            $"Locality:        {placemark.Locality}\n" +
            $"PostalCode:      {placemark.PostalCode}\n" +
            $"SubAdminArea:    {placemark.SubAdminArea}\n" +
            $"SubLocality:     {placemark.SubLocality}\n" +
            $"SubThoroughfare: {placemark.SubThoroughfare}\n" +
            $"Thoroughfare:    {placemark.Thoroughfare}\n";

    }
```

Comment: Hi @Jason, I was going through the same documentation. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've been trying to get the business name or at least type of business with the reverse geocoding. I'm just getting numbers for some things. For example FeatureName is 230. Anyone knows how to translate it?

Comment: I’d guess it’s just bad data, but you’ll get better  answers if you ask your own question